# Django rest framework: I can't update nested objects when data is sent as raw JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework, and I working on api for an ember project.

I'm using the browsable api interface and I able to create and update using the HTML form, but when I try to do the same using raw JSON I get this error:

```
    "propiedad": [
    "This field may not be null."
  ]
```

I've been testing several configurations and I read the documentation and several questions in internet, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**These are my models:**

```
class Propiedad(models.Model): # Datos
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name='Usuario')
    titulo = models.CharField('Título', max_length=100)
    tipo_propiedad = models.ForeignKey('tipos.Tipo_propiedad', verbose_name='Tipo de propiedad')
    tipo_operacion = models.ForeignKey('tipos.Tipo_operacion',verbose_name='Tipo de operación')
    descripcion = models.TextField('Descripción',blank=True, null=True)
    vistas = models.IntegerField('Vistas', blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField('Me gusta', blank=True, null=True)
    precio = models.IntegerField('Precio')
    moneda = models.CharField('Moneda', max_length=4,choices=MONEDA, default=MONEDA[0][0])
    tipo_cobro = models.ForeignKey('tipos.Tipo_cobro',verbose_name='Tipo de cobro', blank=True, null=True)
    expiracion = models.DateTimeField('Fecha de expiración', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Propiedad'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Propiedades'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo

class Datos_generales(models.Model):
    propiedad = models.OneToOneField('propiedades.Propiedad',verbose_name='Propiedad',blank=True,null=True)
    fraccionamiento = models.BooleanField('Fraccionamiento', default=False, blank=True)
    calle = models.CharField('Calle', max_length=100)
    colonia = models.CharField('Colonia', max_length=100)
    numero_exterior = models.CharField('Número exterior', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_interior = models.CharField('Número interior', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    codigo_postal = models.CharField('Código postal', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    edad = models.CharField('Edad del inmueble', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    estado_conservacion = models.CharField('Estado de conservación', max_length=20, choices=ESTADO_CONSERVACION,blank=True, null=True)
    cuartos = models.IntegerField('Núm. Cuartos', blank=True, null=True)
    banios = models.IntegerField('Núm. Baños', blank=True, null=True)
    medios_banios = models.IntegerField('Núm. Medios baños', blank=True, null=True)
    estacionamientos = models.IntegerField('Estacionamientos', blank=True, null=True)
    ubicacion = GeopositionField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Datos generales'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Datos generales'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Datos generales'

class Caracteristicas(models.Model):  # Características generales
    propiedad = models.OneToOneField('propiedades.Propiedad',verbose_name='Propiedad',blank=True,null=True)
    vestidor = models.BooleanField('Vestidor', default=False, blank=True)
    azotea = models.BooleanField('Azotea', default=False, blank=True)
    jardin = models.BooleanField('Jardín', default=False, blank=True)
    cocina_integral = models.BooleanField('Cocina integral', default=False, blank=True)
    comedor = models.BooleanField('Comedor', default=False, blank=True)
    sala = models.BooleanField('Sala', default=False, blank=True)
    cuartos_servicio = models.BooleanField('Cuartos de servicio', default=False, blank=True)
    cuarto_lavado = models.BooleanField('Cuarto de lavado', default=False, blank=True)
    niveles_construidos = models.IntegerField('Niveles construidos', blank=True, null=True)
    mascotas = models.BooleanField('Mascotas', default=False, blank=True)
    acceso_discapacitados = models.BooleanField('Acceso discapacitados', default=False, blank=True)
    amueblado = models.CharField('Amueblado', max_length=30, choices=AMUEBLADO, default=AMUEBLADO[0][0], blank=True, null=True)
    tipo_terreno = models.CharField('Tipo de terreno', max_length=20, choices=TIPO_TERRENO, blank=True, null=True)
    escuelas_cercanas = models.BooleanField('Escuelas cercanas', default=False, blank=True)
    cc_cercanos = models.BooleanField('Centros Comerciales Cercanos', default=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Caracteristicas'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Caracteristicas'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Caracteristicas'

class Amenidades(models.Model):  # Amenidades
    propiedad = models.OneToOneField('propiedades.Propiedad',verbose_name='Propiedad',blank=True,null=True)
    desayunador = models.BooleanField('Desayunador', default=False, blank=True)
    sala_tv = models.BooleanField('Sala de TV', default=False, blank=True)
    terraza = models.BooleanField('Terraza', default=False, blank=True)
    alberca = models.BooleanField('Alberca', default=False, blank=True)
    jacuzzi = models.BooleanField('Jacuzzi', default=False, blank=True)
    salon_juegos = models.BooleanField('Salón de juegos', default=False, blank=True)
    salon_fiestas = models.BooleanField('Salón de fiestas', default=False, blank=True)
    estudio = models.BooleanField('Estudio', default=False, blank=True)
    bodegas = models.IntegerField('Bodega(s)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    vista_panoramica = models.BooleanField('Vista panorámica', default=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Amenidades'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Amenidades'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Amenidades'

class Servicios(models.Model):  # Servicios
    propiedad = models.OneToOneField('propiedades.Propiedad',verbose_name='Propiedad',blank=True,null=True)
    cisterna = models.BooleanField('Cisterna', default=False, blank=True)
    aire_acondicionado = models.IntegerField('Aire acondicionado', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    alarma = models.BooleanField('Alarma', default=False, blank=True)
    gimnasio = models.BooleanField('Gimnasio', default=False, blank=True)
    asador = models.BooleanField('Asador/Parrila', default=False, blank=True)
    calefaccion = models.BooleanField('Calefacción', default=False, blank=True)
    seguridad_privada = models.BooleanField('Seguridad privada', default=False, blank=True)
    servicios_basicos = models.BooleanField('Servicios básicos (agua/luz)', default=False, blank=True)
    gas = models.BooleanField('Gas', default=False, blank=True)
    linea_telefonica = models.BooleanField('Línea telefónica', default=False, blank=True)
    internet = models.BooleanField('Internet', default=False, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Servicios'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Servicios'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Servicios'
```

**My serializers.py file:**

```
class Datos_generalesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Datos_generales
        fields = (
            "id",
            "fraccionamiento",
            "calle",
            "colonia",
            "numero_exterior",
            "numero_interior",
            "codigo_postal",
            "edad",
            "estado_conservacion",
            "cuartos",
            "banios",
            "medios_banios",
            "estacionamientos",
            "ubicacion",
        )

class CaracteristicasSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Caracteristicas
        fields = (
            "id",
            "vestidor",
            "azotea",
            "jardin",
            "cocina_integral",
            "comedor",
            "sala",
            "cuartos_servicio",
            "cuarto_lavado",
            "niveles_construidos",
            "mascotas",
            "acceso_discapacitados",
            "amueblado",
            "tipo_terreno",
            "escuelas_cercanas",
            "cc_cercanos",
        )
```

**My views.py file**

```
class PropiedadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PropiedadSerializer
    queryset = Propiedad.objects.all()
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

This the JSON code that I send to create a new object, to update is the same code, but with the "id" key (obviously :P) on the top:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "titulo": "Praesent egestas neque",
    "tipo_propiedad": 1,
    "tipo_operacion": 1,
    "datos_generales": {
        "id": 1,
        "fraccionamiento": true,
        "calle": "Praesent blandit laoreet",
        "colonia": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique",
        "numero_exterior": "1234",
        "numero_interior": "",
        "codigo_postal": "12345",
        "edad": "10",
        "estado_conservacion": "excelente",
        "cuartos": 3,
        "banios": 2,
        "medios_banios": 1,
        "estacionamientos": 2,
        "ubicacion": "23.241346102386135,-101.953125"
    },
    "caracteristicas": {
        "id": 1,
        "vestidor": true,
        "azotea": true,
        "jardin": true,
        "cocina_integral": true,
        "comedor": true,
        "sala": true,
        "cuartos_servicio": true,
        "cuarto_lavado": true,
        "niveles_construidos": 2,
        "mascotas": true,
        "acceso_discapacitados": true,
        "amueblado": "si",
        "tipo_terreno": "ascendente",
        "escuelas_cercanas": true,
        "cc_cercanos": true
    },
    "amenidades": {
        "desayunador": true,
        "sala_tv": true,
        "terraza": true,
        "alberca": true,
        "jacuzzi": false,
        "salon_juegos": false,
        "salon_fiestas": false,
        "estudio": false,
        "bodegas": 0,
        "vista_panoramica": true
    },
    "servicios": {
        "id": 1,
        "cisterna": true,
        "aire_acondicionado": 0,
        "alarma": false,
        "gimnasio": true,
        "asador": false,
        "calefaccion": true,
        "seguridad_privada": false,
        "servicios_basicos": false,
        "gas": false,
        "linea_telefonica": false,
        "internet": false
    },
    "descripcion": "Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Praesent blandit laoreet nibh. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc.\r\n\r\nFusce fermentum. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Nam eget dui. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.",
    "precio": 3500,
    "moneda": "usd",
    "expiracion": null,
    "vistas": 0,
    "likes": 0
}
```

**Update 2:**

After a lot of tests, I have just discovered that the real problem is the "ember-django-adapter" package.

Comment: Could you add an example of the JSON you're sending it?

Comment: Hi @Hamish, I've just updated my question, Thanks.